# Angular 6 usage of external library, scripts array in angular json

Tags: angular

I have a simple question, I want to use lame js library in angular 6 but I am not able to achive that.

**stackbltiz demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whygjq?file=angular.json

**library lame js:**

https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs

**steps which I done:**

- npm install lamejs
- in angular.json in scripts I have pasted path to node_modules:

> "node_modules/lamejs/lame.min.js"

- and I have stucked how to use that in app component, in other topics here I found sth like: import * as lame from '????'

How to use it in proper way

Comment: Have you tried `const lamejs = require("lamejs");` in your component? instead of `import * as lame..`

Comment: i am not sure but require is from nodejs apps and it wouldn't work

Comment: Well you can also use this. Same as nodejs application. When you use this you not need to import `node_module....` js into `angular.json`.

Comment: Here is the stackblitz that show you how to use `require(yourmodule)` : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhun6j

Answer (score 0):

Click the **Dependencies** panel on the left and add **lamejs**.

Now in your `Component.ts` (or wherever you need it), just import it.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import lame from 'lamejs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  public tryMe(): void {
    var mp3encoder = new lame.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128); //mono 44.1khz encode to 128kbps

    // etc. See quickstart at https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs
  }
}
```